# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can i handle this exception

This is for catch error from JPA persistence

```
try {
    if (platform.getPlatformId() == null) {
        messageString = "inserted";
    } else {
        messageString = "updated";
    }

    Platform platf = platformServiceImpl.addOne(platform);
    model.addAttribute("locations", locationServiceImpl.getAll());

    //Date localDate = new Date();
    //PlatformDetail newDetailPlatform = new PlatformDetail();
    //newDetailPlatform.setLastUpdate(localDate);
    //newDetailPlatform.setPlatform(platform);
    //platformDetailServiceImpl.addOne(newDetailPlatform);
    //redirectAttributes.addAttribute("platformId", platf.getPlatformId());
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success", messageString);
    return "redirect:/admin/step1/" + platf.getPlatformId();

} catch (PersistenceException ex) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "dfdf");
    return "redirect:/admin/step1/" + ex.getCause();
}
```

I expected send a RedirectParameter with the key duplicate and show as a message

Answer (score 0):

In the `catch` section, redirect just to `/admin/step1` or some other endpoint with a message that something went wrong. Adding `ex.getCause()` makes no sense, because `getCause()` returns a `Throwable` object (to be precise: object implementing `Throwable` interface).